# How to render an ejs template from express using fetch without submitting form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

**login.js file:**

```
const form  = document.getElementById('loginForm');

form.addEventListener('submit',async(e)=>{

     e.preventDefault();

   
    return await fetch(`localhost:8000/route`, {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  

}
```

**app.js file:**

```
   app.get('/index',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('route.ejs');
    })
```

I only get the rendered html as a response but can't render it.I know that using form submission works.But can anyone plz tell me how to render the page without submitting form?Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get HTML as a response and not rendered because you use an AJAX call when using `fetch`.  It doesn't instruct the browser what to do with that response.

You have few options.

Either when you get the response back you handle it in your callback like so:

```
return await fetch(`localhost:8000/route`, {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then(res=> {
       let htmlText = await response.text();
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML(bodyContent);
    });
```

Or in fact if you just want to load a new page from your ejs template, set the window to the new location and browser will automatically render the response. Something like so in your `login.js`:

```
document.location.href = "/route_that_returns_html";
```

**Note** that since your question is generic you can take one of the above approach. However as your code suggests if you are trying to implement a login then the right way to do it is in following steps:

1. Let the form submit as usual ( not using ajax/fetch)
2. On server side using express, execute the login routine to authenticate the user.
3. If the authentication passes issue a `res.redirect()` to the authenticated page that renders using ejs or if fails, redirect back to login page with error.

Finally this [DigitalOcean Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) explains how to use ejs properly and is worth a read.